# npm (version 5.5.1) install errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed node version 9.2.0 and npm version 5.5.1

On the command line, I want to install packages:

```
$ npm install express --save
npm WARN bookstore@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\ad\Projects\bookstore\node_modules\bytes
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 
'C:\Users\ad\Projects\bookstore\node_modules\bytes' -> 
'C:\Users\ad\Projects\bookstore\node_modules\.bytes.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-
14T06_36_04_014Z-debug.log
```

What does this mean? Maybe I should uninstall node version 9 and revert to the `LTS`-version 8? And how to do that in Windows?

Please, I need help; thank you in advance!

EDIT: Could it be caused by a slow internet connection; `npm not being able to find a file.`?

EDIT 2: I was able to uninstall node version 9.2.0, then installed version 8.10.0 :-( Still the same error messages!

Answer (score 0):

First Use Below Command

```
touch .npmignore
```

Then Install Express

```
npm install express --save
```

Comment: Sorry, but this gives the same errors. Should the .npmignore file be empty, or should it have content? If so, what?

Comment: It must be empty

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but this is really stupid! Let me explain: I have been using Visual Studio Code for months now, and it's inbuilt command line (bash). Never had any issues with it!
But now; there must be something wrong with VS Code, giving these errors.

I tried an alternative: Git-Bash command window and separately Sublime Text 3. And it works! I could install all dependencies that were needed, without any errors or warnings!

Can someone explain this strange behavior I had using VS Code?